# Repeat content in tabs created with Pmw notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a small application using Tkinter and Pmw. Using the Pmw NoteBook class have an interface to allow the user to create new tabs for input.

Each of these tabs has exactly the same content (radio buttons and entry fields), so I want the content to be written in just one function. But this does not work and I do not understand why not. I get a NameError in the Traceback that does not make sense to me, as "page" has been defined for the whole class, and I can use it in other function definitions.

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'page' is not defined
```

The simplest working version of what I am trying to do is (based on the NoteBook_2 example shipped with Pmw):

```
import Tkinter
import Pmw

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.pageCounter = 0 
        self.mainframe = Tkinter.Frame(parent)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)
        self.notebook = Pmw.NoteBook(self.mainframe)
        buttonbox = Pmw.ButtonBox(self.mainframe)
        buttonbox.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'x')
        buttonbox.add('Add Tab', command = self.insertpage)
        self.notebook.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def insertpage(self):
        # Create a new Tab
        self.pageCounter = self.pageCounter + 1
        pageName = 'Tab%d' % (self.pageCounter)
        page = self.notebook.insert(pageName)
        self.showPageContent()

    def showPageContent(self):
        # This function should contain the content for all new Tabs
        tabContentExample = Tkinter.Label(page, text="This is the Tab Content I want to repeat\n")
        tabContentExample.pack() 

# Create demo in root window for testing.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Pmw.initialise(root)
    widget = Demo(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone give me a pointer to the solution?

Comment: You really need to post the traceback

Comment: The full traceback is:
`
    File "/home/SimpleExample_Tabs.py", line 20, in insertpage
      self.showPageContent()
    File "/home/SimpleExample_Tabs.py", line 24, in showPageContent
      tabContentExample = Tkinter.Label(page, text="This is the Tab Content I want to repeat\n")
    <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'page' is not defined
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showPageContent` is using the variable `page` which is undefined. You define it locally in another method, but it isn't known to the `showPageContent` method. You either need to use `self.page`, or pass `page` to `showPageContent`:

```
page = self.notebook.insert(pageName)
self.showPageContent(page)
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan this was just the pointer I needed.

For anyone trying to use this answer: You will need to define showPageContent as:

`    def showPageContent(self, page):`

otherwise there will be a complaint about the number of arguments being passed on to that function in your traceback.